# Missing postgresql.auto.conf after a reload

Tags: postgresql

I had to update my pg_hba.conf file with new host entries and after reloading I see the below messages in log file.

skipping missing configuration file "/var/lib/pgsql/11/data/postgresql.auto.conf"

The file is indeed missing in the location.
Is there a way we could restore this file or recreate this file.

Thanks,
Sri

Changed the configuration file  and reloaded the database.
Users to be able to access from the new hosts to the database.

Comment: Maybe it is intentionally missing.  That is just a log message, not an error.  You can ignore it unless that file is supposed to be there and supposed to contain something important, which we can't know.  You could restore by copying it from a file-level backup, if you have one of those.

Answer (score 1):

You can simply recreate the file with `ALTER SYSTEM`, using a configuration parameter that is set to default:

```
ALTER SYSTEM SET cursor_tuple_fraction = 0.1;
ALTER SYSTEM RESET cursor_tuple_fraction;
```

But I would worry if someone or something randomly deletes files in a data directory. If these data are important for you, perform something like

```bash
pg_dumpall -f /dev/null
```

and see if you get any error messages.

Comment: Thanks, it works and resolved the issue.